# Parse out Variable Names and array index from a DSL

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

So I need to parse out variable names and array indexes from a DSL

The string that has the DSL could tag these forms

```
"DoSomething(car); blahdoSomethingElse(house.blah)"

"DoSomething(building3[4], building, houseA[5]); blahdoSomethingElse(thing.blah567[8])"

"DoSomething(building[4].foo[6]); blahdoSomethingElse(thing.blah567[8])"
```

the variables could be up to 4 layers deep. ie. Layer1.Layer2.Layer3.Layer4

Also, the variables are always going to be in a function call i.e. wrapped in Somefunction()

What I need out of these is a `List<(string Name, int? index)>` for the string.

How can I accomplish this? is there some library I can use or will I need to use regular expressions, if regex is needed how should I go about it?

Comment: Parsing is an enormously big and fruitful area of results in computing, and there are many tools and libraries that will help generate parsers. Using hand-written regexes can be a quick way to get started, but also a quick way to get nowhere fast if the actual language turns out to be even slightly more complicated than your regexes can actually handle.

Comment: There is no easy way to do it, you need some specialised DSL parsing generator. Look into ANTLR.